# PHP PDO dynamic update query to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form with an image upload and text inputs. it keeps replacing the `profile_picture` field with NULL. Therefore, I'm trying to create a dynamic update query, where if one value is empty it's excluded from the query altogether.

Any help is appreciated.

IMAGE UPLOAD:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['profile_picture']) && $_FILES['profile_picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    // Rename the uploaded file
    $uploadName = $_FILES['profile_picture']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['profile_picture']['tmp_file'];
    $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadName, strripos($uploadName, '.')+1));
    $filename = round(microtime(true)).mt_rand().'.'.$ext;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_picture']['tmp_name'],'../profile_picutres/'. $filename)) {

}

}
```

UPDATE QUERY:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE 001_user_table_as SET profile_picture=:profile_picture, first_name=:first_name, last_name=:last_name, phone_number=:phone_number, nationality=:nationality, years_experience=:years_experience, data=:data WHERE id=:id");

 $stmt->bindParam(':profile_picture', $filename);
 $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':phone_number', $phone_number);
 $stmt->bindParam(':nationality', $nationality);
 $stmt->bindParam(':years_experience', $years_experience);
 $stmt->bindParam(':data', $cv_data);
 $stmt->bindParam(':id', $user_id);

if($stmt->execute()){
$response["message"] = 'success';   
}else{
$response["message"] = 'error'; 
$errors++;
}
```

Comment: Add the complete error message and the generated statement

Comment: for reference: A canonical example I wrote: [PDO examples. How to create a WHERE clause for PDO dynamically](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where)

Comment: As of your (overly complicated) code, you have at least a double colon, may be other issues. Why don't you echo the resulting query out and just see the SQL?

Comment: wait. it's UPDATE. you are trying to use a helper code for SELECT to create an UPDATE query.

Comment: Yes, well it didn't have a dynamic example for an update query. so I thought I could modify the SELECT query. guess I was wrong. I have an update query as I explained above, it's just it keeps replacing the image field with NULL.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_update

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @YourCommonSense one thing though, how can I get it to accept not only `$_POST` variables. I tried modifying this line `$params[$key] = $_POST[$key];` and put just `$key` but that didn't work.

Comment: you need to assemble your variables into array, where the key is a field name and the value is a value to be updated. $_POST is just an example, you can use any other array, but it should be an array to utilize the loop. If you don't want/like arrays, then you could use your old approach with separate variables, but implode your pairs not with OR but with ,

Comment: I changed it to this  `$setStr .= "$key =: $key,";  $params[$key] = $GLOBALS[$key];` and seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution, where an input is empty, it'll use the existing data in that field and will accept not only `$_POST` variables, but all variables.

```
// the list of allowed field names
$allowed = ["profile_picture","first_name","last_name", "phone_number", "nationality", "years_experience", "data" ];

// initialize an array with values:
$params = [];

// initialize a string with `fieldname` = :placeholder pairs
$setStr = "";

// loop over source data array
foreach ($allowed as $key)
{
    if (!empty([$key]) || $key != "" || $key != NULL)
    {

        if($GLOBALS[$key] != NULL){

        $setStr .= "`$key` = :$key ,";
        $params[$key] = $GLOBALS[$key];

        }else{

        $setStr .= "`$key` = $key ,";

        }

    }else{



    }
}
$setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");

$params['id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$dbh->prepare("UPDATE 001_user_table_as SET $setStr WHERE id = :id")->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on a global variable, you could use a function to generate the SQL string that depends only on a table name, allowed columns and columns provided. This allows you to react to any source of request (forms, raw body, ...).

```php
<?php

function getPreparedUpdateSql(string $table, array $allowedColumns, array $columns): string
{
    $set = [];

    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        if (!in_array($column, $allowedColumns)) {
            continue;
        }

        $set[] = "$column = :$column";
    }

    $set = implode(", ", $set);

    return "UPDATE $table SET $set WHERE id = :id";
}
```

And here is an example usage of that function anywhere you need it.

```php
<?php

$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1", "user", "pass");

$jsonRequestBody = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
// ["firstname" => "firstname", "lastname" => "lastname"]

$entityId = 1;

$table = "users";

$allowedColumns = ["firstname", "lastname", "email", "role"];

$columns = array_keys($jsonRequestBody);
// ["firstname", "lastname"]

$sql = getPreparedUpdateSql($table, $allowedColumns, $columns);
// UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname WHERE id = :id

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);

$query->execute([...$jsonRequestBody, "id" => $entityId]);
```

If you want to use it on traditional forms, you can simply change the `columns` variable to this.

```php
<?php

$columns = array_keys($_POST);
```

Do not forget to check for thrown exceptions!